# PHP regular expression replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to split **alpha-numeric** (with space) and **non-alpha-numeric** by comma in a string.

I tried with this...

```
$str = "This is !@#$%^&";
preg_replace("/([a-z0-9_\s])([^a-z0-9_])/i", "$1, $2", $str);
```

But I got this result...

> This, is, !@#$%^&

How can I fix the search pattarn to get this result?

> This is, !@#$%^&

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have negated everything in the first group for the second, like so:

```
preg_replace("/([a-z0-9_\s])([^a-z0-9_\s])/i", "$1, $2", $str);
```

Otherwise, it'd split on spaces as well.

Comment: That would work for his example text but, because the regex for splitting is static, it will probably not work for anything else

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? Can share some examples where it'd fail?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to do this in multiple iterations. Try this:

```
$preg = array( "/([\w\s]+)/i", "/([\W\s]+)/i" ):
$replace = array( "\\1, ", "\\1 " );
$result = rtrim( preg_replace( $preg, $replace, $input ) ); // rtrim to get rid of any excess spaces
```