# Purpose of parenthesis in regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

i dont undestand the () in regexp.

eg. what is the difference between these lines:

```
"/hello/"
"/(hello)/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By wrapping it in ( and ) you can capture it and handle it as a whole. Suppose we have the following text:

> hellohello hello!

If I wanted to find the word "hello" in two's, I could do this:

```
/hellohello/
```

Or, I could do this:

```
/(hello){2}/
```

Comment: so the above example would give the same result?

Comment: For finding "hello" twice, yes. You could manually put it in twice if you wanted, but imagine something like `/(hello){50}/`. This is a very limited demonstration though.

Comment: nice example..gave u green one for that:) could u please explain these two () in the following code, i cant understand it: '/<a([^>]+)\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/i'

Comment: It's a backreference. Typically these are used to store parts of the expression for later use. You can see the following question for an example of backreferences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695427/php-regular-expression-replace

Answer (score 6):

() provide a way to capture matches and for grouping take a look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for a more full description.

Answer (score 1):

As you have written it, there is no actual difference between the two examples. But parantheses allow you to apply post-logic to that entire group of characters (e.g. as another poster used as an example, {2} afterwards would state the the string "hello" is typed two times in a row without anything in between - hellohello. Parantheses also allow you to use "or" statements - "/(hello|goodbye)/" would match EITHER hello OR goodbye.

The most powerful use of them however is extracting data from a string, rather than just matching it, it lets you pull the data out of the string and do what you want with it.

e.g. in PHP if you did

```
preg_replace( "/hello (.+)/i", "hello how are you?", $holder );`
```

Then $holder[1] will contain ALL the text after "hello ", which in this case would be "how are you?"